# What is memory layout of C program for null initialized global pointer variable?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, elf

I have written a short program to check the memory allocation area of `ptr1` and `ptr2`.
I found that `ptr1` and `ptr2` are present in `.bss` (Uninitialized data segment) since I have initialized both with `NULL`, My question is how come they can go in .bss section?

As per my understanding, they should be part of .data segment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *ptr1 = NULL;
int *ptr2 = NULL;

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because the compiler is smart. Sure it can place it in the data segment with a 0 value but it has figured out it is more efficient to place it in the BSS. The end functional result is the same.

Comment: The compiler knows that it doesn't need to initialize the variables because you never use the values you assign.  So it doesn't initialize them even though you told it to because you'll never know anyway.

Comment: bss may be commonly referred to as "uninitialized", but what it really means is "initialized to 0, the default".  (And this means that those 0's don't have to be stored as explicit data in the program file; the OS can trivially generate them with the equivalent of `memset(bss, 0, bsssize)` at load time.)

Answer (score 0):

The widely used segments "bss" and "data" contain both initialized variables. The difference is that the segment "data" will be loaded with values from the application's image<sup>*1</sup>. The segment "bss" will be initialized with zeroes.

Since there is no need to store a lot of zeroes in the application's image, common system don't do it. So only the initial values of the "data" segment are included in the image. You might look at this as a primitive kind of context-aware compression.

If you define a static variable without explicit initialization, the C standard promises that it will be zeroed, which is an implicit initialization. Therefore, the explicit initialization with a zero value<sup>*2</sup> is equivalent. However, it makes your source code easier to understand, where applicable.

*Note: Another common segment is "rodata", which contains all read-only static variables.*

***1:** Such an image can be the executable file in your file system, or in case of a simple embedded system some section in flash.

***2:** `NULL` is a pointer with such a value.